# Secure keypair encryption solution in Delphi & PHP?

Tags: delphi, security, encryption, rsa, lockbox-3

My application sends encrypted files over the internet, I need to be able to do the following:

1. (**Client side Delphi 2010)**: Encrypt files using **public key shipped with my application** & upload it to server
2. (**Server side PHP)**: Decrypt the uploaded file using my **private key stored on server**
3. (Work on the uploaded file...)

Sounds simple but I can't find any reliable code/component, I found these components:

1. [DCPcrypt](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/dcpcrypt). This is what I'm using right now in development but doesn't seem to support keypair-based encryption (RSA?)
2. [GnuPgp](http://www.gnupg.org/) (GPL) so I can't use it on my commercial app.
3. [TurboPower LockBox 3](http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/HomePage): does support keypair encryption but very cryptic (no documentation AFAIK) and doesn't seem to support file encryption.

**My question is:** is there a **secure / reliable** encryption component that:

1. Achieve what I described above (ie. keypair encryption)
2. Can be decrypted using PHP
3. Works on **large files/streams**
4. (**Dreaming here!**) Has a simple delphi/php demo that shows how to do this? :)
5. FOSS solutions only please, I'm already wayyy over budget :)

Comment: Good crypto for free makes little sense -- it requires quite a lot of skills in both programming, security and math.

Comment: Usually you won't crypt an entire file using RSA or the like, because it is usually slower. You encrypt with a symmetric algorithm, than encrypt the key used with the asymmetric one. As long as you use a correctly implemented standard algorithm data will be usable from both PHP and Delphi. LockBox 3 IMHO is not a good library.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp: Do you have a nice discount coupon laying around that you can give me for SecureBlackbox? :)

Comment: @Gdhami if you contact me privately.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with OpenSSL.
PHP seems to have plenty of support for it, though I haven't actually tried it:
For example [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) and [an example here](http://andytson.com/blog/2009/07/php-public-key-cryptography-using-openssl/).

Delphi can be made to work well with OpenSSL with a little work, using stuff I've mentioned on here numerous times: http://www.disi.unige.it/person/FerranteM/delphiopenssl/. Some good examples on that page too. And take a look at the Indy OpenSSL imports.

Not specific components but definitely free, flexible and with full possibilities for shooting yourself, security-wise, in the foot :-)

EDIT:

For Delphi I would consider using the EVP_Seal* functions and you can find my version of a cut down libeay32.pas file in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9733823/197962). You ned this as Indy doesn't surface or implement much/any of the actual EVP_ functions so you need to import the function declarations and a few other routines.

For PHP [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-open.php) seems the right counterpart.

As a bonus, this should give you an idea of how to use the EVP_Seal* stuff (non-tested):

```
function EVPSeal(ASource: TBytes; const APublicKey: PEVP_PKEY; out Key: TBytes; out IV: TBytes): TBytes; 
var
  cipher: PEVP_CIPHER;
  ctx: EVP_CIPHER_CTX;
  buf: TBytes;
  block_size, buf_start, out_len, keysize: integer;
  ek: array[0..0] of PByte;
  ekl: array[0..0] of integer;
  pubk: array[0..0] of PEVP_PKEY;
begin
  keysize := EVP_PKEY_size(APublicKey);
  cipher := EVP_aes_256_cbc;
  SetLength(IV, EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);
  SetLength(Key, keysize);
  ek[0] := @Key[0];
  pubk[0] := APublicKey;
  buf_start := 0;
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(@ctx);
  try
    EVP_SealInit(@ctx, cipher, @ek[0], @ekl, @IV[0], @pubk[0], 1);
    block_size := EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(@ctx);
    SetLength(buf, Length(ASource) + block_size);
    SetLength(Key, ekl[0]);
    EVP_SealUpdate(@ctx, @buf[buf_start], out_len, @ASource[0], Length(ASource));
    Inc(buf_start, out_len);
    EVP_SealFinal(@ctx, @buf[buf_start], out_len);
    Inc(buf_start, out_len);
    SetLength(buf, buf_start);
    result := buf;
  finally
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(@ctx);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah, crypto. There is a saying about a programmer that knows little crypto being far more dangerous than one that knows none.

On a really similar vein, I spent quite some time trying to find a way to do digital XML signatures using open source. I only [managed to get so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929650/sha1-hashing-in-delphi-xe) before buckling up and getting a [rock solid third party library](http://www.eldos.com/). It is not cheap in the pure monetary sense, but one of my best investments so far.

*(True story: I actually got into a little flamewar with the author of this library that even got deleted from the comments. Alas, I ended up buying from him. Go figure.)*

Comment: So, is your answer *no*, or *yes, but it's harder than I was willing to pursue, and I got into an argument with someone once*?

Comment: @RobKennedy - if you feel the answer is not worthy your time then downvote away.

Comment: I'm just not sure what your answer *is*.

Comment: That you will spend either time or money? I provided a link to a previous question that contains links to several open source libraries, and also to a commercial product that, IMHO, is just what you need if you need crypto in Delphi. Didn't have anything else to add because just there isn't much (even less given that GPL is ruled out.)