# AES library compatible with openssl

Tags: delphi, openssl

I have a linux c++ server application witch sends AES128 encrypted strings. The library that the application is using is open SSL.

Is there any delphi library I can use to encrypt data witch needs to be sent to the server . I have found an unit but the data isn't decripted ok between the server and client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting Key, IV and parameters right is usually the toughest part.

I got the AES implementation from [Delphi Encryption Compendium](http://code.google.com/p/delphidec/) in Delphi 2007 on Windows to encrypt/decrypt stuff coming from an AS/400 without much trouble.

Another route you can follow is [use the OpenSLL binaries on Windows and use Delphi wrappers around them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723963/delphi-pascal-example-for-calling-openssl-evp-functions).

Answer (score 0):

[TurboPower Lockbox 3](http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/tiki-index.php) contains OpenSSL but I have never actually used it before.

[image]