# Unable to load public key to memory

Tags: delphi, openssl

I have generated a pair of private/public keys and I have managed to load the private key to sign some bytes. The problem ocurrs when I try to load the public key from memory to verify the signature.

Here is some code :

```
  privateKey := BIO_new(BIO_s_mem);
  PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(privateKey,rsa,enc,nil,0,nil,PChar('1234567890'));
  publicKey := BIO_new(BIO_s_mem);
  PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(publicKey,rsa);
  WriteLn(GetErrorMessage);
  //No error so far
  Writeln('Keys generated!');
  pKey := nil;
  PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(privateKey,pKey,nil,PChar('1234567890'));
  // pKey is ok
  mKey := nil;
  PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(publicKey,mKey,nil,nil);
  WriteLn(GetErrorMessage);
```

The error message output by the last line is

```
PEM routines : PEM_read_bio : no start line
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I'd suggest looking on how Indy is doing it...

Comment: if u can't use OpenSSL, then perhaps using other libraries ? LovkBox3, Spring4Delphi, etc ?

Comment: openssl is pretty fast and I would like to understand what am I doing wrong rather then switching to something else

Comment: @TobyAllen : PEM routines : PEM_read_bio : no start line

Comment: Two things to look at for debugging: Is `mKey` being populated with anything at all? Also, what do you get if you just try to read everything from `publicKey` (using `BIO_read()` or similar); i.e. does what is being written to memory _look_ like a valid PEM-encoded object?

Comment: @atomicinf : mKey = nil if i Use BIO_read() the output is a PEM-encoded object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing `PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey()` and `PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY()`. The former writes a PKCS#1 RSAPublicKey structure, while the latter expects a SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure. The two structures are not interchangeable, hence your error upon read.

To resolve this error, use `PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY()` when writing your public key to BIO.

Comment: I will try your suggestion and come back with an answer later this day.Thanks!

Comment: PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY is not defined in the unit I use.Could you supply a definition for it ? Thanks

Comment: @opc0de From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723963/delphi-pascal-example-for-calling-openssl-evp-functions: `function PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(bp: PBIO; x: PRSA): integer; cdecl;` I don't actually do Delphi, but I work with OpenSSL on an almost daily basis. Had the wrong function here originally; just woke up >_>